# Laravel ErrorException Undefined variable in my public function

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, php-7

I ran into the error:

`ErrorException Undefined variable: pesan`

I have gone through similar problems solved here but none of the solutions have worked for me.

The error is thrown from my RegisterController at bottom of the line. At the `pesan`

I use laravel 8

Here is my controller code:

`       public function simpan_rm(Request $request)
{

```
    $this->validate($request, [
        'idpasien' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:1,4',
        'keluhan_utama' => 'required|max:40',
        'anamnesis' => 'required|max:1000',
        'px_fisik' => 'max:1000',
        'diagnosis' => 'max:40',
        'dokter' => 'required',
    ]);
   // Decoding array input pemeriksaan lab
   if (isset($request->lab))
   {
        if (has_dupes(array_column($request->lab,'id'))){
            $errors = new MessageBag(['lab'=>['Lab yang sama tidak boleh dimasukan berulang']]);
            return back()->withErrors($errors);
        }
        $this->validate($request, [
            'lab.*.hasil' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:1,4',          
        ]);
        $lab_id = decode('lab','id',$request->lab);
        $lab_hasil = decode('lab','hasil',$request->lab);
   }
   else {
    $lab_id ="";
    $lab_hasil ="";
   }

   // Decoding array input resep
   if (isset($request->resep))
    {
        if (has_dupes(array_column($request->resep,'id'))){
            $errors = new MessageBag(['resep'=>['resep yang sama tidak boleh dimasukan berulang']]);
            return back()->withErrors($errors);
        }
        $this->validate($request, [
            'resep.*.jumlah' => 'required|numeric|digits_between:1,3',
            'resep.*.aturan' => 'required',
        ]);
        $resep_id = decode('resep','id',$request->resep);
        $resep_jumlah = decode('resep','jumlah',$request->resep);
        $resep_dosis = decode('resep','aturan',$request->resep); 
    }
    else {
        $resep_id = "";
        $resep_jumlah = "";
        $resep_dosis = "";
    }
    $newresep = array();
    $oldresep=array();
    if (is_array($request) || is_object($newresep))
    {
    foreach ($request->resep as $resep){
        $newresep[$resep['id']] = $resep['jumlah'];
    }
    }
    if (empty($oldresep)) {
        $resultanresep = resultan_resep($oldresep,$newresep);
    }
    else {$resultanresep=$newresep;}
    $errors = validasi_stok($resultanresep);
    if ($errors !== NULL) {
      return  back()->withErrors($errors);
    }

    foreach ($resultanresep as $key => $value) {
        $perintah=kurangi_stok($key,$value);
        if ($perintah === false) { $habis = array_push($habis,$key); }
    }

    DB::table('rm')->insert([
        'idpasien' => $request->idpasien,
        'ku' => $request->keluhan_utama,
        'anamnesis' => $request->anamnesis,
        'pxfisik' => $request->px_fisik,
        'lab' => $lab_id,
        'hasil' => $lab_hasil,
        'diagnosis' => $request->diagnosis,
        'resep' => $resep_id,
        'jumlah' => $resep_jumlah,
        'aturan' => $resep_dosis,
        'dokter' => $request->dokter,
        'created_time' => Carbon::now(),
        'updated_time' => Carbon::now(),
    ]);

       $ids= DB::table('rm')->latest('created_time')->first();         
        switch($request->simpan) {
            case 'simpan_edit': 
                $buka=route('rm.edit',$ids->id);
                $pesan='Data Rekam Medis berhasil disimpan!';
            break;             
            case 'simpan_baru': 
                $buka=route('rm.tambah.id',$request->idpasien);;
                $pesan='Data Rekam Medis berhasil disimpan!';
            break;
        }
   
     return redirect('buka')->with('pesan',$pesan);  
     
}`
```

Unfortunately i've modified `return redirect('buka')->with('pesan',$pesan);` but didn't work for me.
Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", "Warning: Undefined array key", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-warning-undefined-arr)

Answer (score 1):

`$pesan` is defined in 2 cases of your switch statement.

So what happens when `$request->simpan` is neither equal to `simpan_edit` or `simpan_baru` ?

In this case (wich is not handled in your code), `$pesan` will be undefined and an error will throw.

A good practice using switch statements is to add a `default:` case wich will match any other values that you didn't explicitely set a `case:` for.

Example :

```php
switch($request->simpan) {
    case 'simpan_edit': 
        $buka=route('rm.edit',$ids->id);
        $pesan='Data Rekam Medis berhasil disimpan!';
        break;             
    case 'simpan_baru': 
        $buka=route('rm.tambah.id',$request->idpasien);;
        $pesan='Data Rekam Medis berhasil disimpan!';
        break;
    default:
        // you may set a default value for `$pesan` here
        $pesan=null;                
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the error is related to the $pesan variable, according to the code you've provided, $pesan is not defined anywhere in the controller, which is why you're receiving the Error Exception Undefined variable : pesan error
for resolve this issue, you should either define the $pesan variable or remove any reference to it in the code
if $pesan is meant to store some message, it should be defined and assigned a value before being used